# If I implement UTF-16 file handler, can it accurately process all other encodings

Tags: java, file-io, character-encoding

I am writing a small scale HTML crawler in java. I want to have a single file handler that can open all the HTML file one by one and process them. But, there is no way to know what the HTML file is encoded in before actually opening that particular file. So, I am willing to know if I can have something like this :

```
new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(file), UTF16));
```

and the handler will be able to read all possible encodings (in an accurate way) the files may have (my idea is `UTF16` is backward compatible with all other encodings). I will have to deal with following encodings.

```
charset=iso-8859-1
charset=utf-8
charset=iso-8859-1
charset=iso-8859-15'
charset="UTF-8"
charset=windows-1252
charset=utf-16
```

Thanks. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what design pattern are you contemplating using to accompilsh this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No UTF16 can only understand files encoded in UTF16. Your best bet lies in determining the encoding before you process the file. Use the [GuessEncoding](http://glaforge.free.fr/wiki/) library to detect the encoding and then construct the reader in the encoding detected.

I'd use this in combination with **Jon Skeet's** suggestion

Comment: Pangea, thanks for the clue regarding the UTF16. To be frank with you, I hate those n-gram ...blah..blah...statistical methods. Actually, I am in this field of NLP and they do it so much here that I am fed up with those things. I would rather follow standard rules and assumptions and miss the contents out there which are not well structured and don't abide by rules.

Comment: The utility doesn't depend on n-gram stuff. It is purely based on BOM's. Find more details here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GUESSENC/Home . I think this is toolkit is doing the same thing proposed by @Joshua and this is being used by IntelliJ (and also my project) and the results are consistent

Comment: Many thanks for that tips, Pangea. I used the library with success in my work. Thanks for bringing me back to track :D. Saved me lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 3):

No, UTF-16 is certainly *not* compatible with all other encodings (in that you can't use a UTF-16 decoder to decode any old text). Try using it for UTF-8, ISO-Latin-1 or any number of other encodings and it will fail.

Assuming this HTML has been fetched from a web server, you should remember the content type given in the response. Alternatively you could heuristically guess the encoding, of course.

Comment: I am wondering if the contentType is going to work in all scenarios. This is is only as good as the server-side code serving the content right

Comment: @Pangea: Yes, if the server lies about it and you can't guess from the content itself, you're stuck. Ultimately there are cases where the text could be valid but different in two different encodings - if you don't have a hint, there's absolutely no way of knowing how it should be interpreted.

Comment: Thanks, friend. Since this world is a bit messy, I am integrating your suggestion with Joshua algo. i.e. read some characters first and then rely on content type.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. Just wow.

The only way to do this is to read the first few hundred bytes in a safe encoding such as Windows-1252 and look for the NULLS that indicate UTF-16/32 and the META charset tag.

Failing in that, look at the headers for a charset.

If no header found, assume UTF-8 (standard) unless it parses out, then assume Windows-1252 (common error is sending Windows-1252 with no charset header).

Comment: You're supposed to always look at headers for first guess but wrong headers is so common that you can't do that.

Comment: Thanks, friend. Your idea sounds very good for me although there will be some by-product things to do. Thanks.

Comment: I think the GuessEncoding library mentioned by Pangea below carries out the algorithm described by Joshua. I implemented that library with success in my work.